# Convert high DPI images to lower DPI for printing throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image, printing, dpi

I have some images that I'am trying to print out. Those images can come in varying format, from different DPI's to different formats (JPEG, PNG, etc.)

Now what I've done for now, is to load the image into my application and try and 
 convert the dpi to say 96. However in this process i get an OutOfMemoryException, and I'm not sure how to continue.

```
Private Sub PrintImage(Optional providedPrintDialog As PrintDialog = Nothing)
    Dim objPrintDialog As PrintDialog
    If providedPrintDialog IsNot Nothing Then
        objPrintDialog = providedPrintDialog
    Else
        objPrintDialog = New PrintDialog()
    End If
    Dim myPanel As New StackPanel
    myPanel.Margin = New Thickness(15)
    Dim myImage As New Controls.Image
    Dim tempBitmapImage = ConvertBitmapToXDPI(Me.SelectedFileViewModel.File.GetPath, 96)
    Dim tempBitmapImageWidth As Integer = CInt(objPrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth)
    ' A4 max width = 793
    If tempBitmapImage.Width > tempBitmapImageWidth Then
        myImage.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Uniform
    Else
        myImage.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None
    End If
    myImage.Source = tempBitmapImage
    myPanel.Children.Add(myImage)
    myPanel.Measure(New System.Windows.Size(objPrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, objPrintDialog.PrintableAreaHeight))
    myPanel.Arrange(New Rect(New System.Windows.Point(0, 0), myPanel.DesiredSize))
    objPrintDialog.PrintVisual(myPanel, "Billede") ' <- OutOfMemoryException thrown here
End Sub

Private Function ConvertBitmapToXDPI(path As String, newDpi As Integer) As BitmapSource
    Using bitmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path), Bitmap)
        Dim bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], bitmap.PixelFormat)
        Dim bmSource = BitmapSource.Create(
            bitmapData.Width,
            bitmapData.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr24, Nothing,
            bitmapData.Scan0,
            bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height,
            bitmapData.Stride)
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData)
        Return bmSource
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried a `Using` for the `MemoryStream`? You're also returning before the `End Using`. I haven't ever tested but that might mean that it doesn't function properly

Comment: @AFriend You can return from a using block, or even throw an exception. It will always be handled properly.

Comment: Step through it in the debugger and see what line gives the OOM exception

Comment: @KScandrett it is shown as a comment in the source above

Comment: If this is WPF you might want to add that Tag; otherwise why are you using `System.Windows.Media`?

Comment: @Plutonix it is WPF. Using that to try some stuff out

Comment: You appear to believe that dpi is an intrinsic property of a bitmap.  It is just the ratio of pixels to the original defining length.  It is conversion factor to physical dimensions (those that you can measure with a ruler). You can render a given bitmap at a different dpi to yield a physical representation that will have physical dimensions that differ from the original.  You appear to be trying to main the same number of pixels (width x height).  Is that what you really want to be doing?

Comment: We need the exception stack. Have you debugged it to see what line throws?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to do any DPI conversion. Just create a DrawingVisual and draw a BitmapImage into it with an appropriate size:

```
Dim image As New BitmapImage()
image.BeginInit()
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
image.UriSource = New Uri(path)
image.EndInit()
image.Freeze()

Dim size As New Size()

If image.Width < printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth Then
    size.Width = image.Width
    size.Height = image.Height
Else
    size.Width = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth
    size.Height = size.Width / image.Width * image.Height
End If

Dim visual As New DrawingVisual()

Using dc As DrawingContext = visual.RenderOpen()
    dc.DrawImage(image, New Rect(size))
End Using

printDialog.PrintVisual(visual, "Billede")
```

Comment: This actually seem to fix the issue. The ram usage when printing though is still quite high, but it doesnt throw the exception. Qutie Acceptable!

Comment: If you know in advance that the image has significantly higher resolution (i.e. more pixels) than the print area, you may set the BitmapImage's DecodePixelWidth before loading. Depending on the codec this may save a considerable amout of memory.

Comment: You may at least also freeze the BitmapImage. See my edit.

Comment: As a note, if you want to ignore the image file's "native" DPI, you may use the BitmapImage's PixelWidth and PixelHeight properties instead of Width and Height.